# Java generics - wildcards extending multiple types

Tags: java, generics, types, wildcard

I'm trying to do something like the following, but the compiler complains when I do:

```
class A {}

interface B {}

ArrayList<? extends A implements B> list;
```

I've also tried

```
ArrayList<? extends A & B> list;
```

Why isn't this legal? [The Java docs specify an example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) like this

```
class C<T extends A & B> {}
```

So why not allow it in a type definition?

Comment: you have to define A as class A implements B{}, simply saying A implements B doesn't make it true when you define the type inside the ArrayList.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz - But a subclass might.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz 1) I don't have control over class A, it's a class in an API I'm given; 2) I'm not trying to say that class A implements interface B, I'm trying to specify that every object in the ArrayList both extends class A and implements interface B, similar to what's seen in the Oracle example.

Comment: perhaps A is not defined first as stated in the last bit of the Java doc you linked? In your example it is but perhaps in the actual code it is not?
 @Mark

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz in my code the class is listed first in the generics, as specified in the documentation. Additionally, I was able to get the example in the documentation to work with my actual class and interface, but I can't get something like what's in my question to work

Comment: @shmosel sorry for asking a duped question, I searched but didn't see any question that had an answer to this. Can you show me the question that this one is duplicating?

Comment: It's linked up on top.

Comment: @shmosel thanks, I only saw the 'marked as duplicate' comment at the bottom and didn't notice the link at the top. I guess it shows I don't spend a ton of time on this site. Thanks for the link!